# Select an item in a combobox and set the combobox text to a different one?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I want to make a `ComboBox` where the user can type an integer value into the text area, but the drop-down list contains several "defaults" values.  For instance, the items in the drop-down list would be formatted like this:

- Default - 0
- Value 1 - 1
- Value 2 - 2

What I want is that when the user selects an item (e.g. "Default - 0"), the `ComboBox` text will display only the number "0" rather than "Default - 0". The word "Default" is just informational text.

I have played with the following events: `SelectedIndexChanged`, `SelectedValueChanged`, and `SelectionChangeCommitted`, but I was not able to change the text of the `ComboBox`.

```
private void ModificationCombobox_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender; // That cast must not fail.
     if (comboBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
     {
        comboBox.Text = this.values[comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()].ToString(); // Text is not updated after...
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a class for your `ComboBox` item, then create a `List<ComboBoxItem>` and use it as your `Combobox.DataSource`. With this you can set `ComboBox.DisplayMember` to a property you want displaying and still get reference to your object from `ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged()`:

```
class ComboboxItem
{
  public int Value { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  List<ComboboxItem> ComboBoxItems = new List<ComboboxItem>();
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    ComboBoxItems.Add(new ComboboxItem() { Description = "Default = 0", Value = 0 });
    ComboBoxItems.Add(new ComboboxItem() { Description = "Value 1 = 1", Value = 1 });
    ComboBoxItems.Add(new ComboboxItem() { Description = "Value 2 = 2", Value = 2 });
    comboBox1.DataSource = ComboBoxItems;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";

  }

  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var item = (ComboboxItem)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
    var test = string.Format("Description is \'{0}\', Value is  \'{1}\'", item.Description, item.Value.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(test);
  }
}
```

[edit]
If you want to change displayed text when box toogles between DropDown states try this: (this is a concept, not sure how that would behave)

```
    private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
    }

    private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly with your concept! (I've edited your code to add the storing and restoring of the selectedIndex in order to keep the modification)